# How to short the Controller actions in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, controller, ruby-on-rails-3.2

```
def index
    @customers = current_user.customers
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @customers }
    end
  end

  def show
    @customer = current_user.customers.find(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @customer }
    end
  end

  def new
    @customer = current_user.customers.new
  end
```

This is a little part of my CustomerController. The origin `@customers` was `@customers = customers` and so on.

I wanted to index/show/new just for the current_user. This is working, but i had to manually change all the Controller actions.
And also all my automated spec files are just testing for `@customer = customers`.

This seems not the rails way to change all of them manually.

Is there a better solution for this?

thanks in advance
best regards
denym

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly you are asking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Rails way to tackle this would be using the [inherited_resources](https://github.com/josevalim/inherited_resources) gem in combination with [Responders](https://github.com/plataformatec/responders). Exactly your use case is described in the [Overwriting Defaults section of inherited_resources](https://github.com/josevalim/inherited_resources#overwriting-defaults).

This approach is also discussed in the chapter "Writing DRY Controllers with Responders and Generators" in José Valims book [Crafting Rails Applications: Expert Practices for Everyday Rails Development](http://pragprog.com/book/jvrails/crafting-rails-applications).

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for a before_filter. Something like:

```
before_filter :valid_user, only: [:index, :new, :show]

def valid_user
  redirect_to root_path if current_user.nil?
end
```